# Creating an image with imshow

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib, imshow

I am trying to create an image when I have three arrays, the first two contain the pixel coordinates in x and y direction while the third one has the value each pixel should have. In the x direction there are 275 pixel and in the y direction there are 72. The x array consists of 72 times the entry 1, then 72 times the entry 2 and so on. The y array consists of entry counting up to 72 and then starting over again, so in total it counts to 72 275 times. For each of these pixel points I have a value for that specific pixel called rad.

```
fig = figure()
frame = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
im = frame.imshow((ix, iy, rad), cmap="inferno")
fig.colorbar(im)
show()
```

But the output image appears to be a flat one instead of a square one.

**Output of the code**

[image: Output of the code]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your image consists of 3 rows. First row is `ix`, second row is `iy`, last row is `rad`.

Comment: IOBE is right, imshow only takes one array as an argument. You should leave out ix, and iy. If you don't want to/can't do that see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want pcolormesh, rather than imshow. imshow works best when you want to display an array. As such it would only take rad as an argument. Instead you want pcolor which takes x and y coords, as well as an array showing the values at each x,y coord.

The catch is that ix, iy and rad all need to be the same dims for pcolor to work. This is easy however using `numpy.meshgrid` which will take them and generate the arrays you need. Try the following:

```
xx,yy = numpy.meshgrid(ix,iy)
frame.pcolormesh(xx,yy,rad,cmap='inferno')
```

This should work.

Comment: This code will not work. Since ix already contains 19800 entries, you'll create a meshgrid of 19800**2 entries. However `rad` only has only 19800 entries.

Comment: I've re-read OP's question and I don't think this is true. OP has 3 arrays and they look like this

x = array([72, 144, 216, 288, ...])
y = array([1,    2,    3,     4, ...])

It wasn't clearly explained but I think they meant that x is not evenly spaced and rad is 275x72 in shape.

Comment: Not sure where 19800 came from

Comment: All arrays in the question need to be 1D arrays and they need to have the same shape, else you'd get an error from the shown code. As the questions says *"In the x direction there are 275 pixel and in the y direction there are 72"*, meaning 275*72=19800 entries in each of them. It may of course be that the information in the question is inaccurate. In that case the use of pcolormesh as shown here would additionally have the problem that it only shows 19454 of the 19800 elements.

Comment: my understanding of the OP's question is that they have two 1D arrays that have the shapes (275) and (72) and a third array, rad, which has the shape (275,72). In this case, rad has 19800 elements, but ix and iy only have 275 and 72 respectively. Thus performing meshgrid(ix,iy) is appropriate to produce two arrays of x and y coordinates that have shapes (275,72). This in turn facilitates the usage of pcolormesh.

Comment: Yes, this answer is given under that assumption and if that was the case, is correct. However if the respective arrays had the shape assumed here, the code in the question would not result in the shown image, but instead throw an error. Meaning, either the question is unclear, or it shows wrong code, or this answer does not answer it.

Comment: I have found the problem already, the spacing between points was not equal, thus imshow was not very happy about that. I have used another method and have it working now. The total lengt of array x and y are also of 19800 elments each. It bassically has the gridpoints in arrays. So x =(1, 1, 1, ..., 275, 275, 275) and the y array consits of y =(1, 2, 3, ..., 71, 72 ) but still has lengt 19800